# C# - Can't add item to Data Grid View from another class

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a string to the data grid view from another class.

Here is my code:

```
public void AddGridViewRows(string SuccessProxy, string SuccessURL)
{

Console.WriteLine("Called AddGridViewRows");

int row = 0;
dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
row = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;

dataGridView2["doneProxy", row].Value = SuccessProxy;
dataGridView2["doneStatus", row].Value = "Passed Splash";
dataGridView2["doneURL", row].Value = SuccessURL;

dataGridView2.Update();

Console.WriteLine("Successfully added to grid");
}
```

The console returns both but nothing appears in the data grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public void AddGridViewRows(string SuccessProxy, string SuccessURL)
{
Console.WriteLine("Called AddGridViewRows");
dataGridView2.Rows.Insert(0, SuccessProxy, "Passed Splash", SuccessURL);
Console.WriteLine("Successfully added to grid");
}
```

Comment: What does it says?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. The data grid view just remains empty.

Comment: It has 3 columns

Comment: Replace rowindex with 0 and tell me.

Comment: Same thing. I have tried writing the value of SuccessProxy and SuccessURL to console and get the values correctly. When I try to add things to the grid through a button it also works. However through this method I created it makes no change to any data grid views.

Comment: Did you mean Rows.Insert? That way it still doesn't work. I also just tried I can't change any textbox values from the method. Do you know what may be causing this? Thanks for all the help